# How to find elements greater than or less than in a list on random number

Tags: c++, loops, automation, arduino-ide

I have a list of elements (random numeric numbers) that are constantly varying at the output(100 indices), and I want to do with it is if any number generated at output(even if one) is equal or above number '27' turn led on, but if numbers are all less than '27' turn led off. The logic I created for it is not working, even though i am getting output of numbers above value 27 (like 25,26.5,27.8, 23, 29.01, 30.87,23.....so on) still LED is not accurately turning on. Here is my part of code from Arduino:

```
 for (int x = 0 ; x < 101 ; x++)  
  {
    Serial.print("Pixel ");
    Serial.print(x);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.print(myList[x], 2); #myList has got the 100 random numeric values
    Serial.print("C");
    Serial.println();
    if(myList[x<100]>=27) 
       digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  
    if(myList[x<10]<27) 
       digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);     

  }
```

Comment: `myList[x<101]`-> `myList[x]` ?

Comment: The expression `x<101` is a condition that will always be `1` (for true) or `0` (for false). In your case `x` will *always* be less than `101` so `x<101` will always be `1` in your loop.

Comment: What is the type of `myList`? Because, seeing its usage, it has to be a `bool myList[]`. What I'm pointing is the usage of `x<101` inside the brackets, certainly not what you want to do...

Comment: Also note that when `x == 100` then you are really accessing element number 101, since indexes are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve your problem is to find the largest value in the array. This can be done using a single pass (loop) over the array.

If the largest value is less than `27`, the *all* values are less than `27`.

If the largest value is equal or larger than `27`, then that condition is satisfied.

You can "optimize" this by breaking out of the loop when you find a value equal over `27`, and you don't need to find a larger value.

Comment: oh oki. Do you know how to find maximum value in arduino?

Comment: @hns A `for` loop and `>` comparison?

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple search algorithm, it may help you:

```
void loop{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    boolean found = false;
    int x = 0;
    while(x<101 && !found){
        if(myList[x]>=27){
            found = true;
        }
         x++;
    }
    if(found) digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    else digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```

Comment: tried this! it is making the LED blink with random numbers above and below 27, but not constantly keeping the LED on if any 1 or more out of 100 number is above 27.

Comment: is there any other way to check if there is any above 27 value in myList[x] where x is between 0 and 100? 
myList[x<100]>=27) is not the right logic for it?

Comment: No, when you use an array you have to use an index beetwen [], when you use "x<100" is like saying true or false, what is wrong.

Comment: About the solve.... you can put `boolean found = false` outside the function loop, but once the led turn on, it will be turned on until you specifies when turn off (for example: when the array "myList" changes)